# Create a model to identify the next available day based on waiting times

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to create a operating theatre management tool. There is a list of patients waiting for operations and the time each operation takes. I also have a list of the time capacity of each theatre per day. I want to get the sheet to tell me what day the next availability is based on the total time of booked operations. For example if I have 16 hours of operating to do, I know the next available day is Thursday (because the capacity on Tuesday (today) is 8 hours, Wednesday has 4 hours, and Thursday has 8 hours)

[image]

I have tried various ways around this problem

Comment: Perhaps there is information missing here? It seems you have just given us one piece of the puzzle (list of theatres time capacities). Please update your question to include a sample list of patients and their operation times including expected results.

Comment: This seems like a classic input / output problem or more correctly an Assignment problem. This can be solved, with sufficient information (like capacities and demands) using the Solver available in Excel. If you need a reference then check out Practical Management Science by Albright and Winston, the assignment model is covered.

Comment: Great thank you. I will check the Assignment section in solver

Comment: @JvdV there is a table with a list of people waiting for surgery and the estimated time for their operation. There is nothing else of interest in this table

Comment: You have only provided information on the theatre capacity per day per theatre. As such, your question is not answerable.  You will need to include information as to how much of that capacity is being used; and, assuming that you will not switch theatres mid-operation, you would also need to know, as a minimum, how long each operation will take.  eg: a five hour operation can not be booked in Theatre 2. What if you have a 13 hr operation (not unheard of if these surgical operating theatres).